# Word for someone who starts to question his faith?

Tags: word-choice, religion

I'm reading a book about a boy who starts to question the existence of God. He believes He's there but he has no proof so he starts to question if He really exists.

Comment: Perhaps *intelligent*? *Perceptive*? *Free-thinker*?

Comment: **feelings of doubt** is the phrase that expresses precisely what you describe .. "starting to.." question God.  (Perhaps also "stupid" would work :) )

Comment: @Centaurus I realize that you changed the possessive adjective "their" to the singular masculine "his" in the title because the OP talks about a boy who is losing his faith, but the noun "someone" is gender neutral...

Comment: Sounds like a pretty basic thought process to me. As humans we should always be questioning things we don't know to be true. Not sure why it needs a special word.

Comment: Intelligent. Anyone who questions mythology can best be described as intelligent.

Comment: @Joe."*Feelings of doubt*"," "*doubting*", "*a period of doubt*", etc, certainly are the most common and idiomatic ways to describe this scenario, up to and including its more intense relative, "*a crisis of faith*". It would be worth your time to post that as an answer (though by this point it'll be buried under all the other, wronger, answers :/).

Comment: Hey DB, it's just that as a SWR, there is no SW ... so I thought just a comment  :O

Comment: What's with the frickin' absurd political commentary on here?  Good grief. OK, many people are aetheists, congratulations. Go read Richard Dawkins.  It's a site about words, we try to avoid political squabbles, I think, if the words in question happen to be politicized in the broad sense. Sorry I started the ruckus with strictly a joke

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're right Mari-LouA. It wasn't because the word "boy" was mentioned but because I'm an old-timer and still use third person masculine for "everybody, everyone, somebody, etc. I have to change that, I know.

Answer (score 10):

The most obvious one that comes to my mind would be **skeptical**.

> Skeptical : having or expressing doubt about something (such as a claim or statement)
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptical

Other words that might fit are **inquisitive**, **doubting**, or **questioning**.

Comment: I don't think these words carry the right connotations. The term skeptic nearly always indicates someone who is openly critical of a particular idea or creed. It suggests an eagerness to engage in debate with others. It can also be used to describe someone who is silent about their criticism, but still suggests a critical, reserved attitude. That may not describe what this boy is experiencing at all.

Comment: @reinierpost While the term "skeptic" has come to be attached to disbelief in deities lately, I feel the term "skeptical" still carries a connotation of general doubt, not specifically relating to theistic beliefs. I read the question as referring to a boy questioning his own beliefs in the absence of proof. I think "skeptical" conveys that point well.

Answer (score 10):

I like *[ambivalent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambivalent)*:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or
>   someone:

We all live our lives on a foundation of faith. Some have faith in science, nature, mankind, or themselves. Others have faith in a transcendent God. As long as we can squeeze all of the evidence and outcomes into our "faith box", we are confident, but let a defining crisis push us out of that box, and suddenly we are plagued with doubts about everything we have believed. Conversion, whether to or from faith in God, always begins with ambivalence.

Voltaire [said](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/doubt):

> “Doubt is an uncomfortable condition, but certainty is a ridiculous
>   one.”

René Descartes [concurred](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/doubt):

> “If you would be a real seeker after truth, it is necessary that at
>   least once in your life you doubt, as far as possible, all things.”

Paul Tillich, a religious man [agreed](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/doubt):

> “Doubt isn't the opposite of faith; it is an element of faith.”

*[Ambivalence](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ambivalence&allowed_in_frame=0)*, forces us to enlarge our frame of reference to explore the powerful poles of reality that confuse our thinking:

> "simultaneous conflicting feelings," 1924 (1912 as ambivalency),
>
> from German Ambivalenz, coined 1910 by Swiss psychologist Eugen
>   Bleuler (1857-1939) on model of German Equivalenz "equivalence," etc.,
>
> from Latin ambi- "both" (see ambi-) + valentia "strength," from
>   present participle of valere "be strong" (see valiant). A
>   psychological term that by 1929 had taken on a broader literary and
>   general sense.

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com

www.etymonline.com

www.goodreads.com

Comment: All the famous philosophers you quote have described this feeling as *doubt*, so why not suggest that as your answer, rather than ambivalence?

Comment: As it's etymology suggests, **doubt** would be an acceptable word to describe the condition, but in my opinion **ambivalence** accentuates the duality of it more clearly.

Comment: ambivalence has **fuck all** to do with the question.  the question is, what do you call someone who **start to** become ambivalent.

Comment: Good morning, @JoeBlow Did you wake up on the wrong side of the bed yesterday morning, or are you always this ornery?

Answer (score 0):

apostate
Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostasy

Apostasy (/əˈpɒstəsi/; Greek: ἀποστασία (apostasia), "a defection or revolt") is the formal disaffiliation from, or abandonment or renunciation of, a religion by a person. One who commits apostasy (or who apostatizes) is known as an apostate. The term apostasy is used by sociologists to mean renunciation and criticism of, or opposition to, a person's former religion, in a technical sense and without pejorative connotation.

The term is occasionally also used metaphorically to refer to renunciation of a non-religious belief or cause, such as a political party, brain trust, or a sports team.

Apostasy is generally not a self-definition: very few former believers call themselves apostates because of the negative connotation of the term.

Dictionary.com

Word Origin and History for apostate Expand
n.
mid-14c., "one who forsakes his religion or faith," from Old French apostate (Modern French apostat) and directly from Late Latin apostata, from Greek apostasia "defection, desertion, rebellion," from apostenai "to defect," literally "to stand off," from apo- "away from" (see apo- ) + stenai "to stand." Used in non-religious situations (politics, etc.) from mid-14c.

Comment: Apostasy and doubt are two entirely different things.

Comment: an apostate is someone who (say, two years ago) "began to doubt" their faith.  (That's what the question is about.)  Considerably later, they completely doubt their face, then they become radicalized, and THEN they are an apostate.

Answer (score -2):

In some religions he would be called **a disbeliever**

> - disbeliever (noun) - one who withholds or rejects belief. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disbelieve)

Answer (score -3):

> Infidel

Or

> Heretic

Depending on which religion you are abandoning.

Comment: -1 does not address the question asked

Comment: "Infidel" sounds like a bad word to me and it was and still used nowadays as a word to indicate someone that has a different faith. "Heretic" has a different meaning and it means a person that he has and professes different faith paths/ideas from the original faith idea. In both cases, your answer does not address the asked question.

Comment: Nobody's "abandoning" anything. If you think membership of a religion requires blind devotion and that you are "abandoning" it as an "infidel" for simply questioning the existence of the unprovable then, well, that's weird.

Comment: I think 'infidel' come close, but it describes the situation from somebody else's perspective, which is not what appears to be called for here.